# C++ C style array as argument with wrong syntax

Tags: c++, syntax

Header file:

```
#ifndef ENEMY_H
#define ENEMY_H
#include "MonsterSkill.h"
#include "PlayerSkill.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

class Enemy
{
public:
    Enemy(long hp, long dmg);
    Enemy(long hp, long dmg, MonsterSkill[] skills);
    ~Enemy();
    long hp;
    long dmg;
    MonsterSkill[0] skills;
    void getAttacked(PlayerSkill skill, Weapon weapon);
private:
    void dying();
};

#endif
```

There are 4 errors:

line 11: expected a ")"

line 15: (int)0 expected an identifier, expected a ";"

line 16: This error is expected, I haven't defined the weapon class yet.

Comment: What is `MonsterSkill[0] skills;` supposed to be? And `MonsterSkill[] skills`?  You seem to be inventing your own syntax. And you do know public data is A Bad Thing?

Comment: like this: `Enemy(long hp, long dmg, MonsterSkill skills[]);`

Comment: `#include "stdafx.h"` should always come befro any other `#include` statements!

Comment: `Monsterskill[0] skills` is supposed to be a container for all the skills the enemy can use. `MonsterSkill[] skills` is supposed to be a parameter for the constructor, as you can see. It's there so that you can create Enemies of the same type with different skills that they can use.

Comment: And why are public variables a bad thing? Are they needing much performance? I'm writing a text adventure for the Windows console, so I don't have to care about performance in this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right header file class:

```
class Enemy
{
public:
    Enemy(long hp, long dmg);
    Enemy(long hp, long dmg, std::vector<MonsterSkill> skills);
    ~Enemy();
    long hp;
    long dmg;
    std::vector<MonsterSkill> skills;
    void getAttacked(PlayerSkill skill, Weapon weapon);
private:
    void dying();
};
```

A vector is right here because I don't know at compile time how many skills each enemy will have.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I see you already figured out the syntax for arrays. Let me give you a bit of background and a recommendation.

As a general rule you should avoid C-style arrays except where there’s no other way. Arrays are dangerous for two major reasons:

- They do not know their own size (i.e. the number of elements). You have to track it manually.
- The first chance they get arrays decay to a pointer to the first element.

For example, decay happens in a function’s parameter list. These three declarations are equivalent:

```
Enemy(long hp, long dmg, MonsterSkill skills[]);
Enemy(long hp, long dmg, MonsterSkill skills[42]);
Enemy(long hp, long dmg, MonsterSkill* skills);
```

Especially note the last one. It’s the most honest because it says exactly what the parameter really is: a pointer to the first element of the array. That also means you can pass any `MonsterSkill*` to that function, even if it’s not a first-element-pointer or refers to an array of different size. This:

```
MonsterSkill single_monster;
MonsterSkill two_monsters[2];
MonsterSkill eight_monsters[8];
Enemy e1(23, 42, &single_monster);
Enemy e2(23, 42, two_monsters);
Enemy e3(23, 42, eight_monsters);
```

will compile, most likely without any compiler warnings. Of course it’s a desaster waiting to happen.

A bit more on size: You declare C-arrays with a specific size, but you have no reliable way to refer to it later – `sizeof(array_variable)` does not work because it gives you the size of the whole array in bytes. There is a trick: `sizeof(array_variable) / sizeof(array_variable[0])`. The overall byte count devided by the byte count of one element is the number of elements. It’s a clunky way to get at the size, though; and it stops working once you pass the array to a function. As shown above, inside the function you’re stuck with a pointer. Getting the array size from that pointer alone is not possible.

Modern C++ has better alternatives to C-arrays:

If you know the size of the array at compile time use `std::array`. That’s basically an array that does not have the two problems from above. Example:

```
Enemy(long hp, long dmg, const std::array<MonsterSkill>& skills)
    : skills(skills)
{
    // access the array’s number of elements:
    auto elem_count = skills.size();
}
```

If you do not know the size at compile time or if the size can change dynamically, use `std::vector`.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I thought that C arrays would work like Java arrays.

Comment: I looked the vector up in the cpp reference, but I didn't find this out: Is it possible, even with additional self-created functions, to delete an element of a vector at an index?

Comment: Yes, it’s possible. You’ll have to create a matching iterator for `erase()`. If you want to delete index n 
you can do a `vec.erase(vec.begin() + n)`. That said, the whole STL runs on iterators, not indexes. Save yourself some significant pain and embrace that concept instead of fighting it.

Comment: Get the size of a C style array in a more sophisticated way: `template<typename T,std::size_t N>std::size_t array_size(T(&)[N]){return N;}`